# Why don't work angular material tooltip, when add to element in ts code?

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

I'm writing code to add angular material tooltip with ts code to angular 7.

In template its added. But tooltip don't work.

```
let outerRect = $('<div  matTooltip="Hello" matTooltipPosition="right"></div>');
```

In template shown:

```
<div mattooltip="Hello" mattooltipposition="right">
```

But don't work when hover to element.

Comment: you can't use directive using innerHTML. for more read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217049/angular-2-how-can-i-apply-directives-to-sanitized-html-innerhtml

Comment: Adding to @MullisS's comment, why exactly are you adding it in the TS Class anyway? Any specific reason? What's that you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.Any solution?

Comment: facing same issue, mattooltip not workinh with innerHtml property binding. Any suggestions

Comment: @SiddAjmera my case, im modifying the mat-calendar and i want to add details in the day cell so i used innerHTML to add htm elements to it including a mat-icon. Sadly, the tooltip directive doesnt work.