# Kentico cloud: problem adding angular html in richTextResolver

Tags: angular, typescript, kentico-kontent

I'm trying to render a structure inside a RichTextField in kentico cloud. Following this tutorial https://docs.kenticocloud.com/tutorials/develop-apps/get-content/dealing-with-structure-in-rich-text i made a ContentType and used as template for my `AngularLink` (which has 2 properties, text and link), then defined a TypeResolver and registered in DeliveryClient

```
new DeliveryClient({
      projectId: 'xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx',

      typeResolvers: [
        new TypeResolver('landing_page', () => new LandingPage()),
        new TypeResolver('angular_link', () => new AngularLink())
      ],
    });
```

the `AngularLink` class provides a richTextResolver

```
export class AngularLink extends ContentItem {
  text: Fields.TextField;
  link: Fields.TextField;
  constructor() {
    super({

      richTextResolver: (item: AngularLink) => {
        return `<a routerLink="${item.link.value}">${item.text.value}</a>`;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The problem is that when i resolve the html with the `getHtml()` method in RichTextField, the `BrowserRichTextParser` inserts the returned string in an element through *innerHTML* and the final result is the anchor tag with an attribute `routerlink` all lowercase.

Is there a better strategy to make angular attributes working inside the standard fow of kentico-cloud-delivery api?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, however it's not easy to solve. Essentially, the problem you are facing is that what you get from `getHtml` method is 'just' a `string` and when you render it via `innerHtml` angular treats its as html, but it can't resolve directives/components in your html.

It *might* be possible in a future that Angular's `innerHtml` directive will try to instantiate and resolve directives/components, but that is not the case currently. Given the complexity of components, lifecycle and DI, I don't think this will get implemented in near future. It may be that the new `Ivy` renderer will make path for this to be possible at some point.

To achieve what you are asking you would need to instruct angular to create components/directives dynamically - Angular has support for this.

Some resources that might be useful for you are:

- [Angular 2: How can I apply directives to sanitized html/innerhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217049/angular-2-how-can-i-apply-directives-to-sanitized-html-innerhtml)
- [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888008/how-can-i-use-create-dynamic-template-to-compile-dynamic-component-with-angular)
- https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-a-component-in-angular
- https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d

Comment: Thank you @Enn, but from the angular side there's no problem, already implemented dynamic html (string) inclusion using a dynamic component and compiling the template on the fly. The problem is that Kentico itself resolve the `ContentItem richTextFields` and its childrens calling somewhere `richTextResolver` and putting the result inside an htmlelement  with *innerHTML*, which wrongly create the attribute routerlink in the parsed element all in lowercase. This is a limitation of the function `innerHTML` because in html attributes should be case-insensitive, but not in Angular unfortunately

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, the output of `richTextResolver` is always a string which just happens to be an html. You get this string by calling `getHtml` (or `resolveHtml` depending on version) on particular `RichTextField` (or `RichTextElement` again depending on version). Can you show example of what the output of your `richTextResolver` is and what it should be?