# Routing link is not working in dynamic html angular 8

Tags: html, angular, components, href, routerlink

> this is my typescript code

```
getFeatureMenu()
  {
    this.featureService.getAllFeatures().subscribe(data =>
    {

        this.featureData=data;
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
         {
             this.theHtmlString+="<li class='nav-item'><a [routerLink]='['/admin/feature']' ng-reflect-router-link='/admin/feature' routerLinkActive='active' class='nav-link'  (click)='show()'><i class='flaticon-dashboard'></i><span>Feature 1</span></a></li>";
         }
     
      });
  }
```

> this is my Component.html

```
   <div class="sidebar-menu-content"  id="MainMenuList">

       <ul class="nav nav-sidebar-menu sidebar-toggle-view" [innerHtml]="theHtmlString" >

</ul>
</div>
```

Scenrio is i am calling getallfeature api and it gives me features list.now i am creating this dynamically and set to innerhtml in .Feature shown in my list but i cannot see the routerlink in html so please kindly do let me know how can i achieve this? Also i donot want to use this

```
template:
<Div>
<a [routerLink]=["/comp11"]> Crisis Center </a>
<a <routerLink]=["/comp12"]> Heroes </a>
<a [routerLink]=["/comp21"]> Heroes </a>
<a <routerLink]=["/comp22"]> Heroes </a>
</ Div>
,})
```

Comment: Why dont you use *ngFor in HTML. You can achieve above using ngfor

Comment: @SahilJalan i know that ngfor but i cannot use this. i want dynamic.basically i am creating feature base role management.

Comment: [see this for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46217049/angular-2-how-can-i-apply-directives-to-sanitized-html-innerhtml?noredirect=1&lq=1)
As far as i know you can not put/apply directive to innerHTML.

Comment: any other solution if you know..

Comment: No! please correct me if i am wrong. you want to inject component dynamically as per the feature/component name coming from API.
If yes, then there are different ways to do that.

Comment: yes please kindly share.

Comment: hello, have you got the solutions, then please share, I had same kind of problem

Comment: @dhruvinprajapati nop..I have have change the structure of code flow